# foreach radio button show more info

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make for each radio button, when it is clicked on to show the div with more infos about that clicked title, when another radio button is clicked then the to show info about that radio button and hide the other one that was clicked on:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="1" />
<div class="event1">
 content..
</div>

<input type="radio" id="2" />
<div class="event2">
 content..
</div>

<input type="radio" id="3" />
<div class="event3">
 content..
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var i = 1;
while(i < 10) {
$('.event' + i).hide();
    $("#" + i).click(function() {
        $('.event' + i).show();
    });
i++;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Schleis its not working, maybe my loop is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="1" />
<div class="event">
 content.. 1
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="2" />
<div class="event">
 content.. 2
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio" id="3" />
<div class="event">
 content.. 3
</div>
```

JS

```
$('input[name=radio]').click(function() {
    $('.event').hide();
    $(this).next('.event').show();
});
```

CSS

```
.event {
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/UKn6D/

Answer (score 3):

You can try changing your loop with "each"

```
$(function(){
 $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $(this).next().show();
   else
    $(this).next().hide();
  });
 });
});
```

It would be preferrable if you assign a class to radio elements to focus specifically on them. Something like "radioElements" should be enough. Or you can also use id with a starter: "radio_1","radio_2" and then use the input[id^='radio_'].

In all the case you can use "each" function.

More deeply, if you want that all other radio "info" cut off change it to:

```
$(function(){
 $("input[type='radio']").each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("input[type='radio']").next().hide();
    $(this).next().show();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of having a while look like that why not simply have

```
<div id="input-container">
<input class="clickable" />
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

This will then work with multiple and the jQuery can just be like this

```
$('#input-container input.clickable').click(function() {
$(this).parent().find('div.content').hide();
$(this).next('div.content').show();
});
```

I haven't actually tested the above but I believe it should work for you & the reason to have the container ID is just to speed your jQuery up as it is faster to attach via #elementID first

Comment: ah yeah hadn't noticed that slight emend to that will do the trick though

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the ID from the selected radio button
  $('div:visible').hide(); //Hide visible Divs
  $('div.event' + id).show(); //Show matched Div
});
```

You'll want to give the divs an additional class name and update the jQuery code here. You'll also want to make sure to assign a name attribute to the input elements so that they are all part of the same group -- assuming they are.